# How to change the mirror of lxc-create?

Tags: repository, lxc

I have an Ubuntu repository server in my network. I want to create a lxc container using `lxc-create`. How can i change the default repository of `lxc-create` to my repository?

There isn't any option available on its manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the environment variable MIRROR to your preferred mirror then use the `lxc-create` command:

```
MIRROR="http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu" SECURITY_MIRROR="http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu" lxc-create -n foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'ubuntu' template has `--mirror` and `--security-mirror` options:

```
lxc-create -n myvm -t ubuntu -- --mirror="http://my-mirror:3142/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" --security-mirror="http://my-mirror:3142/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
```